# Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.TaskbarIcon threw an exception

Tags: windows-7

Upon each boot up of my windows 7 (64) PC I am getting a message as follows:

The invocation of the constructor on type 
'Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.TaskbarIcon' that matches 
the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

I have no idea what it means or how it got there. I did find [this blog entry](http://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/wpf-notifyicon-must-be-used-as-x86-application/) with a very brief discussion of the problem which sounds like it contains a possible solution - but I don't understand it. I.e. I have no idea what steps I take to implement that solution.

**EDIT:** Thinking out loud... so the blog says "requires the WPF application to be running as x86. Running as Any CPU will produce the following uninformative error:"... so presumably there is some "WPF application" (an exe? a lib? what's the filename?) which can be configured (how?) to run as "x86"...

Comment: x86 vs x64 vs AnyCPU is a compile-time setting, so not something you can change as a user. Presumably there is some program set to auto-start on login that doesn't play well with your system. You need to figure out which applications are set to auto-start and then try to start them one by one and see which one doesn't work. Then you need to somehow act on the results of that testing; download a more appropriate version, uninstall the application, yell at the vendor, or whatever else appears appropriate in the particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and stumbled on this post.

I checked the icon on the task bar against the list of installed programs in my control panel. It
turned out to be *Intel Smart Connect*. I clicked "Repair" and restarted. That solved the problem.

Comment: A more advanced solution would be using something like Process Explorer to find out which process the dialog window belongs to.